# How to email admin to notify of a scheduled activity

Tags: activities, scheduled-reminders, civirules, scheduled-follow-up

Apologies if I have missed a completely obvious bit of documentation.

I want to automatically send an email to our admin users if they schedule a phone call for a later date. Eg, if an admin user named Kathy records a phone call activity for a contact, and then schedules another phone call activity for a week later, it would be great if Civi could email Kathy the day before her scheduled phone call is due. The email should be personalised to Kathy, and at least contain a link to the scheduled activity. And preferably the name of the contact she's trying to call.

I've tried Scheduled reminders, but don't know the tokens that might give the activity id and the name of the target contact.

I've tried CiviRules with the email API extension, but couldn't figure out how to get any activity tokens into the email.

So, what am I missing, or indeed, is this possible? Thanks for your thoughts!

Drupal latest, civi 5.21

Comment: This is currently impossible without an extension, but it's *very* close to being possible, and you can probably do it today if you don't mind applying a patch.  See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/send-an-email-to-activity-targets-when-activity-is-created-via-the-api.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send an email to activity targets when activity is created via the API](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/send-an-email-to-activity-targets-when-activity-is-created-via-the-api)